# Difference between two SQL timestamp values

Tags: mysql

How can I find the difference between two SQL timestamp values in minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the TIMEDIFF() function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Example:

```
mysql> select timediff('2010-11-03 15:30:00','2010-11-03 14:00:00') as diff;
+----------+
| diff     |
+----------+
| 01:30:00 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Also do use DATE_FORMAT function, available in the link passed by Ike Walker as needed to format output if needed

Answer (score 1):

Use [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(ts1, ts2) FROM ...
```